# How to force lower case in the title?

Tags: titles, capitalization

I need to force some letters to be lower case in the title because it is part of a mathematician's name (deRham). How can I do that?

Comment: But what document class are you using and how exactly are you building the title? Please provide all information relevant to this issue.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You could use `\MakeLowercase`:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\title{Topics on \MakeLowercase{de} R\MakeLowercase{ham} cohomology}
\author{The Author}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]

I am not sure about using lowercase for the last name; perhaps

```
\title{Topics on \MakeLowercase{de} Rham cohomology}
```

could be better?

Comment: Thank! That works for me. But I guess still some room for improvement because the letters now become too small as compared to others in the title.

Comment: @HuiYu They will just be lower case: the relative size depends on the font design

Answer (score 7):

1. Use of **\Makelowercase{text}** will do the work, but lots of warning messages will come due to variation in packages.
2. use of **\lowercase{text}** will do the same  work. Try any one of them.