# How can I write subsection headings involving constants (a, b, c, d, etc) in a LaTeX document?

Tags: sectioning, subsection, document

I am working on a research paper using LaTeX for an IEEE journal, and this paper involves some constants (say, a, b, c and d). When I write subsection headings involving these constants, for example..

```
\documentclass{ieeeaccess}
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\section{Dynamic Analysis}
\subsection{Changes in the pressure constant $a$}

xxxxxxx yyyyyyy zzzzz
\end{document}
```

This subsection heading is printed in capital letters when I run LaTeX and reviewers are asking me to fix the subsection headings so that the system constants appear in small letters rather than capital letters.

How can I take care of this problem?

Comment: Similar question, [1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/517162) [2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/386241) [3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/58362)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `ieeeaccess` class is, unfortunately, very badly written. Section titles are an example, because the class uses `\uppercase` which may break badly when you try to use some accented letter in a title.

Anyway, that's what they want, so we need to find a workaround for your problem. Here it is:

```
\subsection{Changes in the pressure constant \lowercase{$a$}}
```